# Key sequences in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make AutoHotKey listen to a key sequence, specifically <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> -> <kbd>D</kbd>, and do some action. How can I do that? I couldn't find a way to define a key sequence.

Comment: Check out AutoIt (what autohotkey was based on), _WinAPI_SetWindowsHookEx() function for complete key sequence capture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that lets you press Win+C, then it waits for one more key.

```
#c::
  Input, x, L1

  if x = d
  {
    Send 1 ;do something
  }
  else if x = e
  {
    Send 2 ;do something else
  }

Return
```

See the [Input](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) documentation for more ideas and examples.